# how can i allow users to view their own pending posts in a front-end page

Tags: posts, post-status, moderation

i want to allow users to view their own pending posts in a front end page but when i access the links created for pending post in the database the links doesn't work until the post is approved
[image]
If I access the post GUID the one where the status is "publish" the link works, but the the one with the status "pending" does not.

I want to know what is the difference between a pending post and a published one other than their status so  I can take those changes into account in order for the pending posts links to work for their authors only.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the query will display by parameter from the user role (capacity)

If your role dont have capacity to display the preview mode, you will need to add it in query.

The function below will allow only the author (without capacity to preview mode)

```
/**
 * ALlow the preview pending for post author 
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function allow_pending_listings($qry) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        if ( isset($_GET['p']) ) {

            $post = get_post($_GET['p']); // parameter "p" in url

            // if not in admin and if the post_auhtor is the correct current id
            if ( !is_admin() && $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {

                $qry->set( 'post_status', array('publish', 'pending') );
                // will add the "pending" status to loop query

            }

        }

    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','allow_pending_listings');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Pending) is a post status that awaits a user with the publish_posts capability (typically a user assigned the Editor role) to publish. (pending)

In other words, a post that is pending is a post that is not published meaning that it can not be viewed by not registered users with at least the publish_posts capability (Editor etc). So public users can not view the post. That's why the url is not "working".

The database just keeps the post status of the post. WordPress Core is responsible for handling the posts depending their status. Also I would suggest to not alter by no means the database manually and always use the WordPress API to modify WordPress elements like posts, pages etc

Comment: i actually want to view the pending post just by the author (current user) i don't want it to be viewed by any other user , is there's a way ?

Comment: @ouqasmohamed Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/256443/edit) to clarify what you're trying to do (ie, allow users to view their own pending posts in a front-end page).

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code to allow user can view pending post

```
function allow_pending_listings($qry) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
    $edit_data = get_post($_GET['eid']);    
     if (!is_admin() && $edit_data->post_author == $userdata->ID) {
    $qry->set('post_status', array('publish','pending'));
     }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','allow_pending_listings');
```

Answer (score 0):

In *database* difference is just that — the different status in respective column.

The important difference is what that *means* — WP doesn't consider pending posts public, they *won't* show up in front end of the site and so on. Messing with this behavior usually goes quite poorly, status system is brittle and full of edge cases.

If you want to deal with items that *are* in the future (events for example) you should store that date information in post meta, separately from published dates.

If you want to just access pending post by an authorized user you can look into *preview* functionality, which is automatically exposed in editor for posts that hadn't been published yet.

Comment: do you mean the preview functionality from the dashboard ? i don't get it

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: i know that i can preview it in the dashboard , i'm wondering if i can preview in the site just like any other post but it's visible only for the author

Comment: Just take a preview link and try? There should be API function to retrieve it by code as far as I remember.

Comment: the preview link created for the post in the database does not work with status is pending , but the same link works if the post is approved

Comment: There are _no_ links stored in database, GUIDs are _not_ valid links. The only way to get a valid permalink for the post (if any) is through the API functions in PHP.

Comment: can you expalin a little more which functions and where to find them ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your front end php:

```
    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
     <?php $current_user = get_current_user_id(); ?>
       <?php query_posts('post_status=publish,draft&showposts=4&author='.$current_user);
?>
     <?php else: ?>
     <?php query_posts('post_status=publish&showposts=4'); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this is goona work for pending posts ?

Comment: It should, if not change: <?php query_posts('post_status=publish,draft&showposts=4&author='.$current_user);
?>
to <?php query_posts('post_status=publish,draft,pending&showposts=4&author='.$current_user);
?>

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes.

Comment: it's not exactly what i need , what i need is to show the pending post in the front page that shows all other posts (published ) , this page already exist , the problem is im retrieving all pending and published post and im making a link on their title , but the links of the published ones works but for the pending ones does not it gives a 404

Comment: Can you give me an example of a link that gives a 404? I can actually preview my pending posts in the front end by clicking the Permalink within the Admin area of the post.

Comment: Ok , btw thank you for your time , well i have a widget that shows the last 5 posts for a user including pending ones , i have a hand on the loop i can handle it however i want . so im displaying only post title making them links to "the default wordpress page that shows post", these links are the GUID colomn from posts table in the database url (in this case : mysiteUrl?p=post_id ) so the problem is the links works for the published post but not the pending ones . i can show you but i can't upload images in a comment

Comment: you can view them because you are logged in as an Admin , but in my case it's a simple user that want to show his pending post

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with post statuses marked as protected, which only allows users with edit caps on the post to preview them.

For these cases, this should do the trick:

```php
add_filter( 'posts_results', function( $posts, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) && ( $wp_query->is_single || $wp_query->is_page ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $posts[0] );
        if ( (int) $post->post_author === get_current_user_id() ) {
            $status = get_post_status_object( $post->post_status );

            if ( $status && $status->protected && in_array( $status->name, [ 'draft', 'pending', 'expired', 'rejected' ], true ) ) {
                $handler = function( $posts, $wp_query ) use ( $post, &$handler ) {
                    remove_filter( 'the_posts', $handler, 100, 2 );
                    $posts[] = $post;
                    return $posts;
                };

                add_filter( 'the_posts', $handler, 100, 2 );
            }
        }
    }

    return $posts;
}, 100, 2 );
```